# Group the same list elements and count its occurences in R

Tags: r, list, vector, group-by, count

I have a list element, say for example:

```
l = list("Android", "iPhone", "Android", "iPhone", "iPhone")
```

I want to have 2 vectors that contains the unique list elements and the count of occurrences of the list element.

```
a = c("Android", "iPhone")
b = c(2, 3)
```

How will I do that easily in R? In my situation, I have a big data that's why I'm finding a quick solution to solve this problem. Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Is your goal to just consider only 1st level list in your grouping? What if there is list  associated to an element?

Comment: @MKR -> the list only contains words only :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this? It converts the list to a vector, then make a table, and finally make the table a `data.frame`.

```
dat <- data.frame(table(sapply(l, function(x) x)))
dat
#     Var1 Freq
#1 Android    2
#2  iPhone    3
```

You can access the individual columns if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can unlist and calculate frequencies. Result is a table, where you can access names and values

```
x <- table(unlist(l))

names(x)
[1] "Android" "iPhone" 

str(x)
 'table' int [1:2(1d)] 2 3
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "Android" "iPhone"
```

Answer (score 0):

In that way an easy way could be to use `unlist` function and then apply`table` to get the frequency for each word/name:

```
table(unlist(l))
#Android  iPhone 
#      2       3
```